# Angular 2 :Adding data in the subscribed array causing multiple addition

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am having a strange situation in which I have subscribed to the firebaseObservable with my firebase data.

CODE :

```
login() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()).then((success)=>{
        console.log("Logged in user is ",this.user);
        this.user.subscribe(signedInUser => {
        console.log(signedInUser,"User Data")

        this.userObject = {
            id : signedInUser.uid,
            userName:signedInUser.displayName
        }
        this.userData.subscribe(userData=>{
          console.log("User Dt",userData);
            userData.forEach(user=>{
             console.log("In user parse",user.id,"    ",signedInUser.uid )
             if(user.id == signedInUser.uid )  {
               this.count++;
               console.log("ins the signed user check ",this.count);
             }
            })

      });

        if(this.count ==0){
             console.log("count is 0");
             this.userEdit.push(this.userObject);
           }else {
             console.log("user already exist.");
           }
           this.count=0;
           this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
    })
    })
  }
```

With this code I want to add the user to my firebase database only if user is not already added. The problem is , when I added the users it is getting added multiple times. Can someone suggest me what is wrong in this ?

Comment: the count is incremented **asynchronously**. So, when you test if it is 0, that will **always** be true, because count++ is executed later, asynchronously, when firebase gets the response to its request, and executes the callback function you passed to subscribe().

Comment: Chaining `subscription` inside another `subscription` is always a trouble. It runs more than actually needed and stops at a random time. The behavior cannot be predicted.

Comment: @JBNizet I agree to your solution and it worked as expected once i shift the count check inside the userData Subscription. Please put that as Answer so that I could accept it.

Comment: @Aravind Can you suggest some way.. to avoid that in my case ?

Comment: @vaibhav I'm too lazy to formulate an answer, but this question, in one way or another, is asked twice a day anyway. Feel free to delete it.

Comment: I cant see where is the addition taking place. clean your code remove console.logs elaborate your question i will help